# parse simple terraform file using go

Tags: go, terraform, hcl

I now tried, everything but cant get this simple thing to work.

I got the following `test_file.hcl`:

```
variable "value" {
  test = "ok"
}
```

I want to parse it using the following code:

```
package hcl

import (
    "github.com/hashicorp/hcl/v2/hclsimple"
)

type Config struct {
    Variable string `hcl:"test"`
}


func HclToStruct(path string) (*Config, error) {
    var config Config

    return &config, hclsimple.DecodeFile(path, nil, &config)
```

But I receive:

```
test_file.hcl:1,1-1: Missing required argument; The argument "test" is required, but no definition was found., and 1 other diagnostic(s)
```

I checked with other projects using the same library but I cannot find my mistake .. I just dont know anymore. Can someone guide me into the right direction?

Comment: The following diagnostics are returned: `&hcl.Diagnostic{Severity:1, Summary:"Missing required argument", Detail:"The argument \"test\" is required, but no definition was found.", Subject:(*hcl.Range)(0xc0000719c0), Context:(*hcl.Range)(nil), Expression:hcl.Expression(nil), EvalContext:(*hcl.EvalContext)(nil)}
&hcl.Diagnostic{Severity:1, Summary:"Unsupported block type", Detail:"Blocks of type \"variable\" are not expected here.", Subject:(*hcl.Range)(0xc0000745d0), Context:(*hcl.Range)(nil), Expression:hcl.Expression(nil), EvalContext:(*hcl.EvalContext)(nil)}
`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Go struct type you wrote here doesn't correspond with the shape of the file you want to parse. Notice that the input file has a `variable` block with a `test` argument inside it, but the Go type you wrote has only the `test` argument. For that reason, the HCL parser is expecting to find a file with just the `test` argument at the top-level, like this:

```
test = "ok"
```

To parse this Terraform-like structure with `hclsimple` will require you to write two struct types: one to represent the top level body containing `variable` blocks and another to represent the content of each of the blocks. For example:

```
type Config struct {
  Variables []*Variable `hcl:"variable,block"`
}

type Variable struct {
  Test *string `hcl:"test"`
}
```

With that said, I'll note that the Terraform language uses some features of HCL that `hclsimple` can't support, or at least can't support with direct decoding like this. For example, the `type` argument inside `variable` blocks is a special sort of expression called a *type constraint* which `hclsimple` doesn't support directly, and so parsing it will require using the lower-level HCL API. (That's what Terraform is doing internally.)

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @Martin Atkins, I now have the following code that works:

```
type Config struct {
    Variable []Variable `hcl:"variable,block"`
}

type Variable struct {
    Value string `hcl:"name,label"`
    Test string  `hcl:"test"`
}
```

With that I can parse a variables.tf like:

```
variable "projectname" {
  default = "cicd-template"
}

variable "ansibleuser" {
  default = "centos"
}
```